# Scala Playframework send file

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a string of data, which I get from data in my database. I want to send it to the user, but without creating a local copy of the file, something like

```
Ok(MyString).as("file/csv")
```

But it is not working. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by using `chunked` with an `Enumerator`. I've also used `withHeaders` to specify the content type and disposition of the `Result` to "attachment", so that the client will interpret it as a file to download (rather than opening in the browser itself).

```
import play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator

val myString: String = ??? // the String you want to send as a file

Ok.chunked(Enumerator(myString.getBytes("UTF-8")).andThen(Enumerator.eof))
  .withHeaders(
     "Content-Type" -> "text/csv",
     "Content-Disposition" -> "attachment; filename=mystring.csv"
  )
```

This might not compile right away, depending on the types you're getting from the database.

Come to think of it, this should also work (without the `Enumerator`):

```
 Ok(myString).withHeaders( /* headers from above */ )
```